# Why can I not parse my config.json file in JavaScript using RequireJS?

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have no idea why I'm not able to parse this JSON file in JS using RequireJS.

```js
var settings = require('https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5e9535d3634f8d782606be53');
var parsed = JSON.parse(settings);
var indexPar = document.createElement('p');

window.onload = testJSON();

function testJSON() {
    indexPar.innerHTML = "Full name is " + parsed.fname + " " + parsed.lname + "\nExpiration Date is " + parsed.expdate + "\nCredit Card # is " + parsed.creditcardnumber + "\nCVV is " + parsed.cvv;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/r.js"></script>
```

To my knowledge, it should show this on the main HTML page:

Full name is Harrison Reeves

Expiration Date is 01/23

Credit Card # is 1234 5678 9012

CVV is 000

Comment: errors in the console? try `window.onload = testJSON;`

Comment: @JaromandaX That didn't do anything. I'm pretty sure that JS functions are referenced to with () at the end always, even without objects.

Comment: `window.onload = testJSON();` will run `testJSON()` and assign the result of calling that function (undefined in this case) to `window.onload` ... whereas `window.onload = testJSON;` will call the function `testJSON` on the window load event - you decide which is correct

Comment: also, `indexPar.innerHTML = .... etc` sets the innerHTML of an element that you haven't yet inserted into the DOM ... so, nothing will display in the web page .... creating an element doesn't add it to the DOM for you, you have to decide where you want to put it

Comment: @JaromandaX I inserted "document.body.appendChild(indexPar);" and still nothing.

Comment: are there any errors at all in the browser developer tools console

Comment: @JaromandaX I am unable to check at the time

Comment: then you will need to

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211610/discussion-between-harrison-reeves-and-jaromanda-x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out. Used this $.getJSON function to fetch a JSON file.

```js
$.getJSON( "https://api.jsonbin.io/b/5e9535d3634f8d782606be53", function( parsed ) {
    window.onload = testJSON();

function testJSON() {
   $("#list").html("Full name is " + parsed.fname + " " + parsed.lname + "\nExpiration Date is " + parsed.expdate + "\nCredit Card # is " + parsed.creditcardnumber + "\nCVV is " + parsed.cvv);
}
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<pre id="list"></pre>
```

Comment: This works great except the \n doesn't work and it uses jQuery. Is there a way to do this using pure JS? Also, why doesn't \n make a new line?

Comment: @HarrisonReeves - you use `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest`

Comment: "\n" in HTML doesn't make a new line, unless you are in a `<pre>` element - HTML 101